# Cannot create Azure B2C tenant in Australia region

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I'm trying to create Azure B2C tenant in Australia region but can't find Australia in the region drop down. Documentation says Azure B2C tenant is available in all locations. Am i missing some thing?

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [Data residency of Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/data-residency#data-residency):

> The following countries/regions are in the process of being added to
>   the list. For now, you can still use Azure AD B2C by picking any of
>   the countries/regions above.
>
> Argentina, **Australia**, Brazil, Chile, Colombia, Ecuador, Iraq, New
>   Zealand, Paraguay, Peru, Uruguay, and Venezuela.

So Australia is still in the process to come. It's not available yet at this moment.

Comment: You can up-vote the UserVoice request here:
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/17904601-azure-ad-b2c-data-residency-in-australia